# Get timestamp of video frame using VapourSynth ffms2 plugin

Tags: python, vapoursynth

I'm using this snippet as video source to mess with it later:

```
import vapoursynth as vs
core = vs.core
core.std.LoadPlugin("/usr/local/lib/libffms2.so")

video = core.ffms2.Source("videotest.mkv")
```

How can i get timestamp of specified frame or get list of timestamps for every frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs of [FFMS2](https://github.com/FFMS/ffms2/blob/master/src/vapoursynth/vapoursource.cpp) and [The VapourSynth API-Reference](http://www.vapoursynth.com/doc/apireference.html?highlight=_absolutetime) the timestamp of the frame can be obtained by accessing the `_AbsoluteTime` prop of each frame.

Use `video.frames()` to get an iterator over every frame:

```
for frame in video.frames():
    print(frame.props["_AbsoluteTime"])
```

Here another example:

```
>>> import vapoursynth
>>> s = vapoursynth.core.ffms2.Source(r"Z:\Anime\Serien\Incomplete\Akanesasu Shoujo\[HorribleSubs] Akanesasu Shoujo - 01 [1080p].mkv")
>>> f = s.get_frame(0)
>>> f.props
<vapoursynth.VideoProps {'_AbsoluteTime': 0.043, '_ChromaLocation': 0, '_ColorRange': 1, '_DurationDen': 1000, '_DurationNum': 41, '_FieldBased': 0, '_Matrix': 2, '_PictType': b'I', '_Primaries': 2, '_SARDen': 1, '_SARNum': 1, '_Transfer': 2}>
>>> f.props._AbsoluteTime
0.043
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what i was looking for.